# Useless stack trace in SetUnhandledExceptionFilter handler

Tags: windows, exception

I've been using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter for a long time, and my handler walks the stack and uses dbghelp.dll to convert the addresses into File/Line references. It then writes that to a log file and puts up a dialog with the same information for the user. This USED to work just fine. These days however I'm getting a completely useless stack:

```
1004bbaa: Lgid.dll, C:\Data\Code\Lgi\trunk\src\win32\Lgi\LgiException.cpp:175
10057de0: Lgid.dll, C:\Data\Code\Lgi\trunk\src\win32\Lgi\GApp.cpp:107
7c864191: kernel32.dll, UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x1c7
102158ed: MSVCRTD.dll, winxfltr.c:228
006dc1a7: Scribe.exe, crtexe.c:345
7c817077: kernel32.dll, RegisterWaitForInputIdle+0x49
00000000: Scribe.exe
```

Where 'Scribe.exe' is my application. Now if I walk the debugger from the exception handler back up the stack several frames I eventually get to a completely different temporary stack that actually includes all the calls that led up to the crash. Which is the information I actually want to log for the user. It's as if the exception handler is executing on a separate stack from the main application.

What I need is the stack information for the actual application stack, that includes all the calls leading up to the crash. Is there some easy way to get that from inside the exception handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.eptacom.net/pubblicazioni/pub_eng/except.html I can get the exception's EIP and EBP out of the EXCEPTION_POINTERS 'Context' member. So I tried passing that EBP to my stack walker as it's initial point and it could then walk the application stack correctly. As long as I put the EIP as the first point in the stack walk I get the whole thing.

Comment: How about using RtlCaptureStackBackTrace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204633(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using x64? Could you be hitting http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/ ?

Comment: I'm mostly running XP still so I think my own answer is probably good enough for the moment. I've sent a debug build out to my client to see if I get a decent stack trace now. *fingers crossed*